# AgGrid "Columns Tool Panel" checkboxes, how to trigger onCheck event?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am using Aggrid, and I need to trigger a onCheck event in the sidebar (Columns Tool Panel).
tldt : Is there a way to get the onCheck event of the sidebar (Columns Tool Panel) ?

I don't find the info here : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/side-bar/

and neither here [Tool Panel Columns](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/tool-panel-columns/)

My needs is the following :
My columns can be visible or not when aggrid get loaded the first time.
Then I can tick some hidden column in the side bar to show it up.
But some column can have children column (not aggrid children), so if I tick a parent column (not aggrid parent), child must be also ticked.

Problem is that child can be also parent, so I used onColumnVisible event, and it is cascading.
I don't want the cascading effect.
So I would need a onCheck event.

I used onColumnVisible event, and it is cascading as a child become visible and trigger again. I don't want the cascading effect

I am expecting to have an onCheckEvent so only this column can trigger my function to tick child.

Comment: I finally managed to avoid cascading.
onColumnVisible event has a property named "source" which is equals to "toolPanelUi" when onColumnVisible is triggered from "Columns Tool Panel"

`Object { type: "columnVisible", visible: true, columns: (1) […], column: {…}, source: "toolPanelUi", api: {…}, columnApi: {…}, context: undefined }`


`Object { type: "columnVisible", visible: true, columns: (2) […], column: null, source: "gridOptionsChanged", api: {…}, columnApi: {…}, context: undefined }`

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to avoid cascading.
onColumnVisible event has a property named "source" which is equals to "toolPanelUi" when onColumnVisible is triggered from "Columns Tool Panel"

`Object { type: "columnVisible", visible: true, columns: (1) […], column: {…}, source: "toolPanelUi", api: {…}, columnApi: {…}, context: undefined }`

And has value "gridOptionsChanged" when undirect changed

`Object { type: "columnVisible", visible: true, columns: (2) […], column: null, source: "gridOptionsChanged", api: {…}, columnApi: {…}, context: undefined }`

So I could filter event source to avoid cascading.